# How to access node_modules in Angular 2 quickstart from subfolder

Tags: angular

I followed the Angular 2 quickstart about a month ago, and I wanted to apply it to one of my projects. The application is a MEAN stack, and the Angular 2 code is in a public folder that is a subfolder in the project, kind of like this:

```
client/

---public/

---scss/

---src/

node_modules/

server/

---app/

---src/

package.json
```

The problem here is that they import a bunch of stuff from node_modules, which works fine for them on their small front-end app, but I can't access any of the node modules because the folder is outside of public.

Is there any way to deal with this without needing two separate package.json files and node_modules folders?